# Isotopy-classes of oriented Schoenflies spheres in $S^4$ is a group under oriented connect-sum

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

Given two oriented, smoothly-embedded copies of $S^3$ in $S^4$ (called Schoenflies spheres), one can take an oriented connect-sum of the pairs $(S^4, M_1) \# (S^4, M_2)$.  This puts a monoidal structure on the isotopy classes of Schoenflies spheres, with the unit being the linearly embedded $S^3 \to S^4$.

I know only one proof that this monoid is a group in the literature. I'm wondering if there are any others?

i.e. I'm looking for a published proof that pre-dates 2019.  I strongly suspect one exists, but if I've seen it, I've forgotten.

Bonus question (but does not need to be answered), are there any analogous results for the monoidal structure on smooth structures on $S^4$ using the oriented connect-sum operation? For this, I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: Wouldn't the question make more sense if you add references? You say that you know "only one proof that this monoid is a group in the literature" and ask for other proofs. Which proof do you know? Also what "analogous results for the monoidal structure on smooth structures on $S^4$" are you asking about?

Comment: After the second look I realized that you are probably asking at the end if the monoid of smooth structures on $S^4$ is a group.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: I'm asking for a reference to a proof before 2019, i.e. I do not have references.  You seem to want me to talk about what this question is specifically *not* about.  I don't see the point.

Comment: Which 2019+ proof exists?

Comment: @ChrisGerig: if a proof is already in the literature, the purpose of this thread is to make people aware of it.  If there isn't one (pre 2019) I'd maybe write a short expository argument that outlines how this follows with an elementary argument from published material.  Given the lack of response in this thread I've contacted a few people directly, to verify if this result is known.

Comment: @ChrisGerig here you go: https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.00136

Comment: Perfect! I was betting that it was going to make use of your recent paper with Gabai